# Return response with status code in Express

Tags: node.js, express, post

In my MongoDB/Node backend I have a pretty standard function for adding a new language to the database via a POST request. It looks like this:

```
exports.add = async function(req, res) {
 let request, doc;
 request = new EndpointRequestController(req, res);

 try {
   doc = await request.save(Language, req.body);
 } catch(err) {
   return request.sendError('An error occurred while trying to find existing records.', err);
 }

 request.sendResponse(doc, res.status(201));
}
```

Currently, this is working - in that when the user passes a value in the body of the POST request, the new language is added to our languages collection.

What I'm trying to figure out is, why is this returning a "204" response, rather than the "201" status I'm explicitly sending here as part of the response? How can I edit this to send the "201" response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending response outside the `await` function... you need to put `res.send` inside await function

```
exports.add = async function(req, res) {
 let request, doc;
 request = new EndpointRequestController(req, res);

 try {
   doc = await request.save(Language, req.body);
   res.status(201).send(doc)
 } catch(err) {
   return request.sendError('An error occurred while trying to find existing records.', err);
 }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, @Ashish.